# Calculate price per quantity on add and minus button via javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php

My question is to know how do i calculate total amount when a user input his quantity on the basis of plus and minus button: Like below image
[same as this picture i need to code in js and php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHNdI.png)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.minus, .plus').click(function() {
    var $qty = $(this).siblings('#qty');
    var qtyCounter = parseInt($qty.val());
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus'))
      qtyCounter++;
    else
      qtyCounter--;
    $qty.val(qtyCounter);
    var pricePerUnit = $(this).siblings('#price').val();
    var quantity = $(this).siblings('#qty').val();
    var total = quantity * pricePerUnit;
    $(this).siblings('#total').val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<span class='minus mybtndanger' class="signrm">-</span>
<input type="text" name="qty" class="txt qty mytext" id="qty" value="0" readonly />
<span class='plus mybtnsuccess'>+</span>
<input type="hidden" name="price" class="txt price" id="price" value="100" />
<input type="text" name="total" class="txt total mytotalprice" id="total" value="100" readonly />
```

I need total amount in textbox of all count. and insert it into database on POST

Answer (score 0):

Try following code buddy. It working fine
HTML CODE as follow

```
<button data-id="1" class='minus mybtndanger' class="signrm">-</button>
<button data-id="1" class='plus mybtnsuccess'>+</button>
<input type="text" name="qty" class="txt qty mytext" size="2" id="qty1" value="0" readonly />
<input type="hidden" name="price" class="txt price" id="price1" value="100" />
 = <span class="tot" id="total1">0</span>
<hr>
<button data-id="2" class='minus mybtndanger' class="signrm">-</button>
<button data-id="2" class='plus mybtnsuccess'>+</button>
<input type="text" name="qty" class="txt qty mytext" size="2" id="qty2" value="0" readonly />
<input type="hidden" name="price" class="txt price" id="price2" value="150" />
 = <span class="tot" id="total2">0</span>
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="grandTotal" value="0">
```

And for Jquery code as follow

```
$(".minus").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var qty = $("#qty"+id).val();
    if(qty >0){
        qty--;
        $("#qty"+id).val(qty);
        var getPrice = $("#price"+id).val();
        getPrice = parseFloat(getPrice).toFixed(2);
        var totalAmt = getPrice*qty;
        $("#total"+id).text(totalAmt);
        grandTotal();
    }
});
$(".plus").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var qty = $("#qty"+id).val();
    qty++;
    $("#qty"+id).val(qty);
    var getPrice = $("#price"+id).val();
    getPrice = parseFloat(getPrice).toFixed(2);
    var totalAmt = getPrice*qty;
    $("#total"+id).text(totalAmt);
    grandTotal();
});

function grandTotal()
{
    var cellText = 0;
    $('.tot').each(function() {
         cellText = cellText + parseFloat($(this).html());    
    });
    $("#grandTotal").val(cellText);
}
```

And for your reference I have update my JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xgayLk3f/

Comment: Thanks Fairy for the awesome code, But i need total amount in a different outbox, 1*100 and 2*100 = output must be 300